# How to format graph so that border starts at max x and y and how to replace a plot command

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to format my graph so that the border ends at the max x and max y so there is not extra space between them and the border.  Also, I'm trying to completely replace my first plot command with my second one.  Should I just delete my first plot? Currently, the second plot goes over my first plot, removing most of my formatting.

```
clear all, close all
 %%command to clear all variables and log history
 x = linspace(-pi, pi, 200);
 %creating x variable between - pi and 200 with pi distance between each
 %value
 y = sin(x) + cos(x);
 %Creating y varable with the help of x
 figure
 plot(x,y)
 title('2-D Plot')
 xlabel('Theta (in radians)')
 ylabel('Function Y')
 xlim([-pi pi])
 ylim([-1.414 1.414])
 grid
 plot(x,y,'r--')
 grid
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want.  Which "border" are you talking about?  There are four borders in a graph (North, South, East, West).  Also, any subsequent use of `plot` simply uses the current figure and overwrites it which is what you're doing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit the axes box tightly around the data without manually adjusting the axis limits, use:

```
axis tight;
```

and instead of re-plotting, you can update the relevant properties of the line.

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 200);
y = sin(x) + cos(x); 
figure;
h = plot(x,y); %handle for the line plot
title('2-D Plot');
xlabel('Theta (in radians)');
ylabel('Function Y');
grid;

axis tight;    %to set the axis limits equal to the range of the data
set(h, 'LineStyle', '--', 'Color', 'r'); %Updating the plot with required changes
```